# V-Tiger 6 How to make a Pick List with Database value

Tags: vtiger, picklist, vtigercrm

I am very new V-Tiger CRM. What I would like to achieve is.I have a custom picklist in Create Vendor form. I know I can populate it by adding PickList Values. But I would like to fetch the Nationality from my custom database table .
My Nationality table looks like ( nationality_id    nationality_name ). I need to fetch these values to custom picklist in my vendore create form

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it using customization as below:

1. Open `modules\Vendors\views\Edit.php`

in `process` function add below code:

```
$sql_get = 'SELECT * FROM nationality_table_name'; 
$sql_get_result =  $adb->query($sql_get); 
for($i=0;$i<$adb->num_rows($sql_get_result);$i++){
    $nationality[$i]['code'] = $adb->query_result($sql_get_result,$i,'nationality_id'); 
    $nationality[$i]['name'] = $adb->query_result($sql_get_result,$i,'nationality_name'); 
}    
$viewer->assign('nationality', $nationality);    
parent::process($request);
```

2:  Create new file in given location

> \layouts\vlayout\modules\Vendors\uitypes\Picklist.tpl

```
{strip}
{assign var="FIELD_INFO" value=Zend_Json::encode($FIELD_MODEL->getFieldInfo())}
{assign var=PICKLIST_VALUES value=$FIELD_MODEL->getPicklistValues()}
{assign var="SPECIAL_VALIDATOR" value=$FIELD_MODEL->getValidator()}
{assign var=FIELD_NAME value=$FIELD_MODEL->getFieldName()}

{assign var=FIELD_NAME value=$FIELD_MODEL->getFieldName()}

{if $FIELD_NAME eq 'nationality_dropdown_name'}
<select class="chzn-select {if $OCCUPY_COMPLETE_WIDTH} row-fluid {/if}" name="{$FIELD_NAME}" data-validation-engine="validate[{if $FIELD_MODEL->isMandatory() eq true} required,{/if}funcCall[Vtiger_Base_Validator_Js.invokeValidation]]" data-fieldinfo='{$FIELD_INFO|escape}' {if !empty($SPECIAL_VALIDATOR)}data-validator='{Zend_Json::encode($SPECIAL_VALIDATOR)}'{/if} data-selected-value='{$FIELD_MODEL->get('fieldvalue')}'>
 {if $FIELD_MODEL->isEmptyPicklistOptionAllowed()}<option value="">{vtranslate('LBL_SELECT_OPTION','Vtiger')}</option>{/if}
 {foreach item=PICKLIST_VALUE key=PICKLIST_NAME from=$nationality}
            <option value="{$PICKLIST_VALUE['code']}" {if trim(decode_html($FIELD_MODEL->get('fieldvalue'))) eq trim($PICKLIST_VALUE['code'])} selected {/if}>{$PICKLIST_VALUE['name']}</option>
 {/foreach}
 </select>
 {/if}     
{/strip}
```

Please update the code as per your fieldnames and test. Cheers!!

Comment: Hello , Thanks for the reply.... I am using Vtiger 6.4. May due to that both the locations you suggested are not with me. in layouts I have upto Vendors. But In Vendor folder I resource folder and inside that folder just an js file. In Module area I have same folder structure as said upto Vendors. Inside that I dont have views folder ,Instead im having Model folder and vendors.php file

Comment: If folders are not there then you have create those folder. e.g. if views folder is not present then create views folder on specific location and create new Edit.php file. You can take take refernce of other modules for Edit.php format